# Matplotlib animation with contour

Tags: python, animation, matrix, matplotlib, contour

i have list of 2d array(matrix) which i want to plot using contour plot and produce animation by updating contour plot continuously with consecutive matrix. I had written the code for this but the code displays only first matrix as contour and does not produce animation

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
    import matplotlib.animation as animation

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,coil_OuterRadius,9), np.linspace(0,coil_Width,5))
```

#z is list of 2d array

```
z = temperatureanimation[0]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8),facecolor='white')
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
quad1 = ax1.contourf(x,y,z)
cb2 = fig.colorbar(quad1,ax=ax1)


def init():
    quad1.set_array([])
    return quad1


def animate(iter):
    z=temperatureanimation[iter]
    quad1.set_array(z.ravel())
    return quad1


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate ,frames=range(720),interval=20,blit=False,repeat=True)

plt.show()
```